# Python Instabot ERROR - Photo does not have a compatible photo aspect ratio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am making a Instagram automation program. But I got an error when I uploading that photo. Is there any program to resize images for the compatible aspect ratio.

**Here is my Program:**

```
from instabot import Bot
import os
import random
from PIL import Image
import smtplib

cwd = os.getcwd()

bot = Bot()

bot.login(username="myusername", password="*********")
files_name = os.listdir(f"{cwd}/photos")


def send_email():
    email = "myemail@hostname.com"
    password = "*****************"
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    s.starttls()
    s.login(email, password)
    s.sendmail(email, email, f"Available Photos in Storage {len(files_name)}")
    s.quit()


file = random.choice(files_name)
split_file_name = str(file).split(".")
ext = str(split_file_name[1])

if ext == 'png':
    img = Image.open(f"{cwd}/photos/{file}")
    jpeg_img = img.convert('RGB')
    jpeg_img.save(f"{cwd}/photos/converted.jpeg")
    bot.upload_photo(f"{cwd}/photos/converted.jpeg", "caption")
    os.remove(f"{cwd}/photos/{file}.REMOVE_ME")
    os.remove(f"{cwd}/photos/converted.jpeg.REMOVE_ME")
else:
    bot.upload_photo(f"{cwd}/photos/{file}", "caption")
    os.remove(f"{cwd}/photos/{file}.REMOVE_ME")

if len(files_name) <= 10:
    send_email()
```

**And Here is the photo properties which is not uploading:**

[image: Photo Properties]

[image]

**And here is the error**

```
FOUND: w:640 h:960 r:0.6666666666666666
2021-01-07 12:42:58,239 - ERROR - Photo does not have a compatible photo aspect ratio.
2021-01-07 12:42:58,239 - INFO - Photo 'C:\Users\asus\PycharmProjects\Python_Projects\autoinsta/photos/image.jpg' is not uploaded.
2021-01-07 12:42:58,241 - INFO - Total requests: 35
```

**Please share any program to resize images which is not compatible for instagram.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Here’s a quick list of the most common Instagram photo and video dimensions:

```
Type of Instagram Post  Aspect Ratio    Instagram Post Size

Square Photo             1:1             1080 x 1080px
Landscape Photo          1.91:1          1080 x 608px
Portrait Photo           4:5             1080 x 1350px
Instagram Stories        9:16            1080 x 1920px
IGTV Cover Photo         1:1.55          420 x 654px
Instagram Square Video   1:1             1080 x 1080px
Instagram Landscape Video 1.91:1         1080 x 608px
Instagram Portrait Video 4:5             1080 x 1350px
```

you can use Pillow Python Imaging Library for resize your image

```
from PIL import Image  
im = Image.open("bear.jpg")  
newsize = (1080, 1080) 
im1 = im.resize(newsize) 
im1.save('resized_bear_photo.jpg')
```